# Am I missing something by skipping the end of episode screen?

Tags: alan-wake

Whenever you finish a chapter in Alan Wake, you end up at a screen that says "End of Episode X" with some music in the background:

[image: End of episode]

I've never sat through one of these screens until they go away on their own. Am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not missing out on any story relevant content as far as I know. I've stared at the screen when I finished Episode 1 only to realize that the only thing that plays during these screens are [songs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Wake#Episode_ending_songs).

When the song ends, the Episode Ending texts fades into some kind of mist. The song doesn't start again. Instead, the next episode starts (beginning with the recap of the previous episode).

Comment: So eventually the song simply stops playing back and you remain at that screen?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: You don't need to press any button to advance to the next episode, at least on the PC version, it just moves on automatically a few seconds after the song ends

Comment: In addition, I can confirm for the Xbox 360 that the next episode starts automatically after the song finishes. I was smoking a cigarette outside peacefully when I heard noise coming from the inside. I peeked and saw the recap of the previous episode so I hard to run back in to pause.